# Define functions for the options after initializing Datatable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I trying to use Datatables JS . I have to create a function for `createdRow` callback method after initializing the datatable object. If I could do it at the initial time, it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
            // do some work
        }
    });
});
```

But I should define it after initializing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
    // do several things
    // and finally create callback method
});
```

Is there any way to do this?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Haven't tried this But I think ```$("#example").dataTable()``` returns a ```dataTable``` instance, it that is true, you may want to store the instance in a variable and use it to attach callbacks, like so: ```var dataTableInstance = $("#example").dataTable();``` and later on ```dataTableInstance.createdRow = function() {}```

Comment: Ah, just looked at the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/on()) I think correct way would be ```var dataTableInstance = $("#example").DataTable()``` (notice uppercase "D") and then ```dataTableInstance.on("createdRow", callbackFunction);```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately they do not work. @Varinder: it returns `callbackFunction is not defined error`

Comment: Ah apologies, you'll have to replace ```callbackFunction``` with the logic you want to run, for example: ```dataTableInstance.on("createdRow", function(row, data, dataIndex) { /*do some work here*/ })```

Comment: @Varinder Of course, it was my fault!! thank you, it runs without error but it does not work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find functions like this in your `context` object of your `Datatable` object:

```
$("#example").DataTable().context
```

And for `createdRow` you can add a method as following:

```
$("#example").DataTable().context[0].aoRowCreatedCallback.push({
    fn : function( row, data, dataIndex ) { //do things
                                          },
    sName : "createdRow"
})
```

Comment: No problem ! ;)